# Probability that out of $n$ bags, at least one contains no black ball, if $n$ of $n^2$ balls are black

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am working on SL Parsonson's *Pure Mathematics* and I haven't been able to solve this problem:

$n^2$ balls, of which $n$ are black and the rest white, are distributed at random into $n$ bags, so that each bag contains $n$ balls. Determine the probability that at least one bag contains no black ball.

The answer given in the book is $1-\frac{(n-1)!(n^2-n)!n^{n-1}}{(n^2-1)!}$.

I thought I might start with the fact that there are $\frac{(n^2)!}{n!(n^2-n)!}$ unique arrangements of the balls, and $n-1$ partitions to be placed at intervals of n to divide them into $n$ bags, but I am stuck a little after here.

Comment: As the official solution suggests, work backwards.  Compute the probability that every bag contains exactly one black ball.  (Note that this is indeed the complementary event).  To compute that, just consider how many good slots the next black ball might take and how many total slots are available to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm imagining instead of bags, we have an $n \times n$ grid of dimples where we can place balls. Then we'll consider each column of the grid to correspond to a bag.

You're correct that the number of ways to place $n$ (identical) black balls and $n^2-n$ (identical) white balls on the grid is

$$ {n^2 \choose n} = \frac{(n^2)!}{n! (n^2-n)!} $$

If no column/bag has only white balls, then there must be exactly one black ball in each column. There are $n^n$ ways to do this.

So the probability that some column/bag DOES contain only white balls is the complement of that ratio,

$$ P = 1 - \frac{n^n}{n^2 \choose n} = 1 - \frac{n!(n^2-n)! n^n}{(n^2)!} $$

The given answer has canceled a few terms, reducing (or perhaps unsimplifying) that result using $n! = n (n-1)!$, $n^n = n \cdot n^{n-1}$, and $(n^2)! = n^2(n^2-1)!$

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to consider all the balls distinct (say, numbered from $1$ to $n^2$).

Then the total number of arrangements is

$$ \binom{n \times n}{n}\binom{n \times (n-1)}{n} \cdots \binom{n}{n}= \frac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n} \tag 1$$

Similarly, the total number of arrangements having a black ball in each one (complementary event) is

$$n! \frac{(n^2 -n)!}{((n-1)!)^n} \tag2$$

The ratio $(2)/(1)$is

$$  \frac{n! \, n^n (n^2-n)!}{(n^2)!} = \frac{(n-1)!n^{n-1} (n^2-n)!}{(n^2-1)!}$$